# Sum of column values based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
daychange   SS
0.017065    0
-0.009259   100
0.031542    0
-0.004530   0
0.000709    0
0.004970    100
-0.021900   0
0.003611    0
```

I have two columns and I want to calculate the sum of next 5 'daychange' if SS = 100.

I am using the following right now but it does not work quite the way I want it to:

```
df['total'] = df.loc[df['SS'] == 100,['daychange']].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: What is your expected output for your example data?

Comment: It should be about 0.0236

Comment: You don't want the `sum`  for the second `100` in `SS`?

Comment: I do. For the second 'SS = 100' i want the sum of next 5 'daychange'. E.g (0.0049 - 0.0219 + 0.0036 + ...). I hope i make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `pandas 1.1` you can create a [forward rolling window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer.html) and select the rows you want to include in your dataframe. With different arguments my notebook kernel got terminated: use with caution.

```
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=5)
df['total'] = df.daychange.rolling(indexer, min_periods=1).sum()[df.SS == 100]
df
```

Out:

```
   daychange   SS     total
0   0.017065    0       NaN
1  -0.009259  100  0.023432
2   0.031542    0       NaN
3  -0.004530    0       NaN
4   0.000709    0       NaN
5   0.004970  100 -0.013319
6  -0.021900    0       NaN
7   0.003611    0       NaN
```

### Exclude the starting row with `SS == 100` from the sum

That would be the next row after rows with `SS == 100`. As all rows are computed you can use

```
df['total'] = df.daychange.rolling(indexer, min_periods=1).sum().shift(-1)[df.SS == 100]
df
```

Out:

```
   daychange   SS     total
0   0.017065    0       NaN
1  -0.009259  100  0.010791
2   0.031542    0       NaN
3  -0.004530    0       NaN
4   0.000709    0       NaN
5   0.004970  100 -0.018289
6  -0.021900    0       NaN
7   0.003611    0       NaN
```

---

### Slow hacky solution using indices of selected rows

This feels like a hack, but works and avoids computing unnecessary rolling values

```
df['next5sum'] = df[df.SS == 100].index.to_series().apply(lambda x: df.daychange.iloc[x: x + 5].sum())
df
```

Out:

```
   daychange   SS  next5sum
0   0.017065    0       NaN
1  -0.009259  100  0.023432
2   0.031542    0       NaN
3  -0.004530    0       NaN
4   0.000709    0       NaN
5   0.004970  100 -0.013319
6  -0.021900    0       NaN
7   0.003611    0       NaN
```

For the sum of the next five rows excluding the rows with `SS == 100` you can adjust the slices or shift the series

```
df['next5sum'] = df[df.SS == 100].index.to_series().apply(lambda x: df.daychange.iloc[x + 1: x + 6].sum())
# df['next5sum'] = df[df.SS == 100].index.to_series().apply(lambda x: df.daychange.shift(-1).iloc[x: x + 5].sum())

df
```

Out:

```
   daychange   SS  next5sum
0   0.017065    0       NaN
1  -0.009259  100  0.010791
2   0.031542    0       NaN
3  -0.004530    0       NaN
4   0.000709    0       NaN
5   0.004970  100 -0.018289
6  -0.021900    0       NaN
7   0.003611    0       NaN
7   0.003611    0       NaN
```

Comment: Interestingly approach! Although it seems like `.rolling()` runs way faster. For instance, when I replicate and concatenate the example data with `df = pd.concat([df for i in range(1000)]).reset_index(drop=True)`, this approach took almost 100X more compared to the `rolling` one. This difference is even bigger with more rows in data.

Comment: Big thanks for the answer. Can u pl help with a slightly different problem: how can i take sum of next 5 numbers this time not including the row where SS = 100. For instance, instead of sum of row 1-5, i take the sum of row 2-6

Comment: @Ramsey - added this requirement to my answer.

Comment: Thanks alottt. However, if I am to use to the "hacky" solution i believe I hv to add .shift(-1) but in what place?

Comment: But for the faster method it gives out an error abt "api.indexer", that it is not found.

Comment: I added two approaches to the hacky solution.